# Google Maps iOS SDK , Screen freezes..not working at all

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

I have been working with Google Maps iOS SDK to integrate into my app. I started working with it using Xcode 6.3.1. Meanwhile, Apple released a new version of Xcode 7.0.1 & I tried testing my app with new Xcode version 7.0.1 on iPhone 6 & later devices. It seems to start pretty well. The google maps view showed all the markers with zoom in & zoom out. But when I clicked on any of the markers, the screen freezed with no log whatsoever on the console.

This is something weird. Because the same app when built using Xcode 6.3.1 works fine.

I thought there might be an App Transport Security issue.So I also listed the key in the plist file to load all the links. But that too didn't work out.

Is there anybody who is facing the same issue?

Kindly provide some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI - the latest non-beta Xcode is currently version 7.1 which support iOS 9.1. Your issue is not related to Xcode but the version of iOS. With Xcode 6 you were using iOS 8. With Xcode 7 your are using iOS 9.

Comment: You should post some marker click related code from your map view controller file.

Comment: @rmaddy  Thanks for your suggestion. I have also updated my Xcode Version to 7.1 . But it didn't work out. But later on, when I debugged, i came to know that didTapInfoWindowOfMarker: method is being called twice, which I think is making all the chaos here. Any suggestion over this to resist it being called twice?

Comment: do you have network in the app? xCode 7 requires all connections in https unless u turn that off in ifo.plist file.

Comment: Hey @jaro, I have used following code to allow Xcode for all connections for the app. I hope it's correct.   `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
     <dict>  
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
     </dict> `

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions & help. Apparently, the issue has been solved. Somehow, the textviews on the next viewcontroller that is being pushed were causing the issue. I removed them & it worked regularly. Pretty weird, but it solved the issue. Thanks all.